# how to use missing __builtin_ functions with Clang

Tags: objective-c, clang, built-in

I want to use `__builtin_return()`, `__builtin_apply()`, and `__builtin_apply_args()` in my Xcode project for iOS App, but the compiler shows the following error messages:

```
Use of unknown builtin '__builtin_return'
Use of unknown builtin '__builtin_apply'
Use of unknown builtin '__builtin_apply_args'
```

I found that the Clang did not support those builtin functions. Is there any possible way to use those `__builtin_` functions in the latest Xcode project for developing iOS App?

I want to try using the [**SuperMessenger**](https://github.com/jaredp/jaredp.repo/tree/master/SuperMessenger) for the reason ['Call any super class’s implementation of any method'](https://jpobjc.wordpress.com/2010/09/01/call-a-any-super-classs-implementation-of-any-method/).

It uses __builtin_ functions to accomplish this job.

```
- (long long)superMessage 
{
    int framelength = frameLength;
    _cmd = selector;
    self = (id)&target;
    __builtin_return(__builtin_apply((void(*)())method, __builtin_apply_args(), frame length));
}
```

Comment: You already found that Clang does not support these functions, so you cannot use them.

Comment: Is there any alternative options or equivalent functions?

Comment: Can you describe your actual problem? What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps then someone can suggest a solution.